# How to migrate from table without primary key using Android Room Persistant Library?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have SQLite database which runs in android smoothly but I want to migrate it to Room Persistant library. Here is the SQL for that table.

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (id INTEGER, ownerPersonId INTEGER);
```

I loaded the prebuild SQLite database in room successfully but when I tried to add Account table it says this:

```
 An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey
```

Here is the account table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "ACCOUNT")
data class Account(var id: Int?, var ownerPersonId: Int?)
```

I understand that I have to add @PrimaryKey annotation but adding this annotation creates mismatch with prebuild database and give this erro.

```
Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema
```

Can anyone tell me what to do in this case. How to migrate the prebuild database without having error?

Comment: why don't you just assign primary to an autoincrement column which you don't care about?

Comment: I cannot because the prebuild database don't have any primary key.

Comment: then you can't achieve what you are looking for with Room. It's mandatory to give one field as the primary key. You can read it here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Entity?authuser=1